# 'invalid ELF header' error when loading libyaml module

Tags: node.js, node-modules, libyaml

When I go into node and attempt to require libyaml I get:

```
> require('libyaml')
Error: /home/ubuntu/shadow/node_modules/libyaml/build/Release/binding.node: invalid ELF header
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:485:11)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/shadow/node_modules/libyaml/index.js:7:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I'm using `node version 0.8.12` and `libyaml version 0.2.1`.  Curiously the error is server dependent, but it doesn't seem to be based on the version numbers, because it runs fine on one of boxes with the same versions.

Comment: Guess the module is not installed for the correct machine architecture. Try `npm install libyaml` on the server.

Comment: nice, that upgrades it and it works

Comment: question -- what if i have multiple architectures, though?  npm installs the modules into source control rather than installing from a list on deploy... so if the install was made for one architecture on dev how can you deploy to another on staging or production?

Answer (score 2):

One can also use 'npm rebuild module-name' to recompile the C code on the deployment machine as part of preinstall script.

[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-rebuild.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks vinayr for advising me to run npm install on the production box.  The issue is that they needed to install npm differently.  I resolved that with a pre-deploy command on the box as part of the deploy.  Problem solved.